# What do these configuration items about emqtt cluster mean?

Tags: mqtt

I want my `emqtt` cluster to work well, thus , I need a way to keep my `emqtt` servers together.
So about those items,what does it mean? every iteam. What should I fill out?

Now if I have two machines. `emq@192.168.139.111` and `emq@192.168.139.222`

```
cluster.discovery = mcast
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------

### Cluster with multicast

```
cluster.mcast.addr = 239.192.0.1

cluster.mcast.ports = 4369,4370

cluster.mcast.iface = 0.0.0.0

cluster.mcast.ttl = 255

cluster.mcast.loop = on

cluster.discovery = dns
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------

### Cluster with DNS

```
cluster.dns.name = localhost

cluster.dns.app  = ekka

cluster.discovery = etcd
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------

### Cluster with Etcd

```
cluster.etcd.server = http://127.0.0.1:2379

cluster.etcd.prefix = emqcl

cluster.etcd.node_ttl = 1m

cluster.discovery = k8s
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------

### Cluster with k8s

```
cluster.k8s.apiserver = http://10.110.111.204:8080

cluster.k8s.service_name = ekka
```

### Address Type: ip | dns

```
cluster.k8s.address_type = ip
```

### The Erlang application name

```
cluster.k8s.app_name = ekka
```

Comment: Have you read the emqtt.io documentation? http://emqtt.io/docs/v2/config.html#emq-cluster

Comment: yes I had read it.but,I don`t know how to configure them.for example,about Cluster with multicast ,what is cluster.mcast.addr ? Maybe because I don't understand multicast.